# Google Map Display error in a small window and doesnt expand

Tags: google-maps

I am using google maps on my website and it displays as the following.

[image]

[Website](http://play.mink7.com/navami/projects/view/19)

Click Location Tab to view the Maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the map is hidden at first, you must trigger resize event.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

From documentation

> Developers should trigger this event on the map when the div changes
>   size: google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize').